# Facebook: Why i can't see the post on the user feed after using custom action sharing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm working with Facebook now. I'm trying to share a custom object to user's feed which includes: one photo and link to my app.

However i only see these posts in the Activity Log only. Nothing appears on my wall / feed

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fb_myappid:install?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
theme=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F123123123
```

Comment: Not everything gets shown in newsfeed. As long as it shows up in your activity log, everything went fine.

Comment: I think if things don't show on this person feed, the friends can't see the post. I've tried it and don't see anything (I'm waiting for approval from FB)